# How does this string replacement function work?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```js
var insertProperty = function (string, propName, propValue) {
  var propToReplace = "{{" + propName + "}}";
  string = string
    .replace(new RegExp(propToReplace, "g"), propValue);
  return string;
}
```

This snippet is a part of the code, extracting data from the library. I'm having a hard time understanding this, please help.

Comment: can you identify in the question what specific part of the code you are having troubles understanding?

Comment: I would not be suprised if you tell me the library is called `mustache`, or any other templating lib. The function here replace templates in a given string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insertProperty` - is a anonymical function which get 3 parameters: string, propName, propValue. It return new string with replacing value `{{propName}}` to propValue.

If this function is gettting `string` that is equal `{{hello}} world`, propName is equal `hello` and propValue is equal `bye`, then result after execution of function insertProperty is equal - `bye world`

Answer (score 3):

Your function is accepting 3 arguments.Assuming:

`string="This {{sample}} is just an example {{sample}}"`

`propName="sample"`

`propValue="code"`

So `propToReplace={{sample}}`

`string = string.replace(new RegExp(propToReplace, "g"), propValue)` is a regular expression which will replace `{{sample}}` with `code` and the new string will become

`This code is just an example code`

The second argument `"g"` in `new RegExp()` denote global flag, which means it will replace all occurances of `{{sample}}` with `code` present in your string argument.